# Search Console URL Inspection shows "URL is not on Google" even though I can find it through Google search

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I am using Google Search Console's URL Inspection Tool but I am not exactly sure how it works.

I have submitted a sitemap to Google Search Console and the link shows up in google search but when I use the link on the URL Inspection, it says the 'URL is not on Google' even though it shows up on google search.

I was wondering why this is happening?
Does the URL Inspection only work for pages that were crawled outside of submitted sitemap pages?
Are sitemap pages excluded from the URL Inspection?

Comment: How long has it been since you submitted your sitemap?   Google's tools aren't always instantly up to date.  It could take a few weeks in some cases.

Comment: Whether or not search console allows you to inspect URLs submitted via sitemap, I would not recommend using sitemaps as the sole means of allowing Googlebot to discover URLs.   Google is unlikely to index URLs unless you link to them on your site from other pages.  Even if Google does index them, they are unlikely to rank well.  See [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox)

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s an assumption to say that just because a page shows up in Google search that Google has actually indexed it.  Especially if you’re just using a search like site:example.com. If key word searches return your page then it’s probably safe to assume it’s indexed.  It’s also possible that Google makes several iterations indexing a page before Google says “done”.

Re submit URL, that is one way to tell Google manually about new content. But if you’re comparing Submit URL and a site search, I don’t think that’s a good match.

Lastly, you’ll find that GSC often finds pages without using your sitemap. Google is more likely to crawl your site via links in your pages than using your sitemap.